# How to check if an app has already been purchased - CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

My application can buy an in-app product which I have configured on the google developer account.

The product is a buy-once product. I would like to know how to check if this item has already been bought (in codenameone) and handle it based on result of query.

Here is a code extract:

```
if(p.isManagedPaymentSupported()) {
        if(p.wasPurchased(id)){
            boolUpdate = true;
            Form f = (Form)createContainer(resPath,"Search");
            beforeSearch(f);
            f.show();
        }else{
            Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                   Boolean confirmAction = Dialog.show("Buy Product?","","Yes","No");
                   if(confirmAction){
                       p.purchase(id);
                   }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

According to the codenameone API doc, The "p.wasPurchased(id)" method is supposed to provide this functionality. But this is not the case after installing on my device and making a purchase. The payment process begins again even after the product has been bought. Meaning the "wasPurchased()" check is returning false.

I would like to check if the item is already purchased and based on that either go to the next screen, or begin the purchase process. Please how can I implement this on codenameone?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently managed purchases aren't supported on Android which I'm assuming is the platform you are referring to?

There is an RFE and some code to resolve it but we didn't get around to do it as of this writing: http://code.google.com/p/codenameone/issues/detail?id=731

Comment: thanks. I will look into implementing this. Android was the platform I was referring to. So does the wasPurchased method work for IOS? As that is the next phase of my test after Android.

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't recall that. I think that it should but its been a while since I looked at that code.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will carry on with my testing and post my findings

Comment: I have been able to implement the in-app purchase for android using the native code link you provided above (thanks). I am now testing for IOS and I have run into the same issue with the android. I can buy my configured product but my issue is checking if the purchase has already been made using the wasPurchased() method. Is there any resource you can link me to in order to help me resolve my dilemma?

Comment: Was purchased is implemented in iOS so I'm not sure why its not working for you. There might be issues there since I don't think we used that API in our implementation, we only relied on items you can purchase multiple times in our products.