# Codename One wasPurchased() method : Is it supported on Android devices?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, codenameone

For my Codename One app, I am trying to figure out whether I can tell if an in-app-purchase (non consumable) has already been bought on Android ([code shown in my other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40495272/test-in-app-purchase-in-codename-one-simulator-results-in-null-pointer-exception/40503168#40503168)).

According to this [2014 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23158754/how-to-check-if-an-app-has-already-been-purchased-codenameone?noredirect=1&lq=1) it seems that managed purchases are not supported on Android. However when I test `isManagedPaymentSupported()` on Android it returns true, and I can buy an In-App-Purchase.

So managed purchases seem to be supported on Android. However `wasPurchased()` remains false even after successful purchase although [this Google Group discussion](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1461) seems to say that `ẁasPurchased()` does work indeed.

I tried to reach the [source code for that `wasPurchased()` method](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/payment/Purchase.java) but could not find anything usefull (maybe I did not find the right code pieces).

So I am completely at lost, since my code works on the simulator as expected but not on a real Android device (which could also be faulty). Consequently could someone tell me if `wasPurchased()` is working on Android (in that case my Android device is faulty) or if I have to implement some native Android code to do what `wasPurchassed()` is expected to do ?

**EDIT November 10th 2016 : Solved with suffix "_nonconsume**

As written in the [blog post @Shai showed](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/migrating-to-androids-in-app-purchase-30.html) in his answer by default Google play considers the product as consumable. That's why in case of non consumable product `wasPurchased()` returned false. To make Google Play treat the In-App-Product as non-consumable, **you have to use the suffix "_nonconsume" in the SKU name** in the developper console (eg : "myappfull_nonconsume"). Then wait a few hours after submitting your app to the alpha testing channel and when the app is available, Google play will remember the purchase and `wasPurchased()` will work as expected.

Any help appreciated,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be more useful: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/Ports/Android/src/com/codename1/impl/android/CodenameOneActivity.java#L191-L209

That's the piece that actually gets called. Support for managed purchases was added a few years ago when we migrated to the new Android in-app-purchase 3 API: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/migrating-to-androids-in-app-purchase-30.html

Comment: I did read this article right before starting my project and forgot the crucial part about the naming convention for non consumable purchases! Anyway thanks for the input @Shai! I'll change the sku to myapp_full_nonconsume and  check again if it works now. By the way, I cannot see the naming convention anywhere else on the internet. Is it a requirement from Google or something specific to Codename One ?

Comment: That was it! One has to use the suffix *_nonconsume* in the SKU as in the blog entry you gave! Thanks à lot!